# Copy specific words from Notepad ++ or some other text editor

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

I have a lot of text like this in Notepad ++:

```
User Actions 
 Follow
Online Marketing
@LookSocialMedia
Talk about #socialmedia, #SEO, online marketing, affiliate sales, #SMO, #PPC and much more. Join the discussion.


User Actions 
Following
Mashable Verified account
@mashable
News, resources, inspiration and fun for the connected generation. Tweets by @mashable staff.
```

I would like to extract all twitter handles - get a unique list like this:

```
@mashable  
@LookSocialMedia
```

all Twitter user profiles in one list.

What is the best way to extract those usernames and have unique list of them in one doc?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the bookmarks within Notepad++.

Search for:

```
^@.*$
```

Within `Mark`, checking `Bookmark line` and `Regular Expression` (but not `. matches newline`)

[image]

---

Click `Search` -> `Bookmark` -> `Remove unmarked lines`

[image]

---

You should be left with the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a stepwise approach:

1. save your file to a new location, you'll remove unwanted content from there
2. To remove all non username content:

   - replace all `(?<!@)\b[^@]*`
   - to nothing
     (to get explanation see https://regex101.com/)
3. to remove duplicates :

   - replace all `(\@[^@]+)(.*)\1`
   - to `\1\2`
4. and finally to get one username per line:

   - replace all `(\@[^@]+)`
   - to `\1\n`

Answer (score 0):

This will generate a new file in the same directory as the current file, adding a ".sorted" between the original file name and extension.

In Notepad++ while displaying your input file, hit `F5` then paste the following in:

`powershell -command "get-content '$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)' | select-string -list -pattern '^@' | sort-object" > "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).sorted.$(EXT_PART)"`

Note that this will overwrite an existing file if present.

Run or save the command. Saving will allow you to assign a key combo shortcut. Someone with better PowerShell-fu than I may want to chime in on an easy way to strip the leading blank line in the output file.